# RecycleView findViewById returning issues

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

**Context**
Hi all. I'm having problems and I've looked everywhere and I'm just not getting it. I'm following a youtube tutorial on RecycleView (Coding in flow) however, I'm coming from a tutorial on setting up a MainActivity with fragments so I'm trying to do this inside of a fragment. In the comments, people have had similar problems and he replied by saying that it's basically the same except that inside the fragment you should use getView() however that isn't working.

**What I've done so far to remedy the problem**
I've been looking at SO threads (even ones that are from the same video) and I'm just not getting it, none of their solutions is working for me or the responses they got (if any) were very vague and non-helpful. I've also searched all 300+ comments from that youtube video and looked up other tutorials to see if there's a solution. Not relevant to the problem I'm having but just to get the point across that I've not just types this out of laziness. I've spent the whole day on this problem and I have nothing to show for it

**What I need the code to do**
I need the code to function as per the tutorial found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17NbUcEts9c). I don't believe that the onCreateView is the best place for my code as surely none of the views will be created until that has been run so findViewById wouldn't be possible but what can I do now then? where can I put that code so it will run.

**My code**

PhotosFragment

```
    public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment {
        private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);
            ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_baseline_one, "First Image Title", "Description"));
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_baseline_two, "Second Image Title", "Description"));
            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_baseline_three, "Third Image Title", "Description"));
            mRecyclerView = findViewByActivity(R.id.recyclerView2);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(super.getContext());
            mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(exampleList);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
```

I will supply anything else as needed. I appreciate any help more than you know. This has utterly defeated me.

Comment: @DanielNugent Do you know of any tutorials on how to override onViewCreated(). I've tried to do it based on a google result but I'm not sure it's correct. https://pastebin.com/ZsJ4iEVe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a return statement on the first line of `onCreateView()`, so none of the other code in there will run. Best to move all that other code to an `onViewCreated()` override.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);
 
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
 
  ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
  exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_baseline_one, "First Image Title", "Description"));
  exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_baseline_two, "Second Image Title", "Description"));
  exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_baseline_three, "Third Image Title", "Description"));
  
  // Use findViewById() on the view:
  mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);
  
  mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
  mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
  mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(exampleList);
  mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
  mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```